# Exception handling - run function again by nesting or looping?

Tags: python, exception, while-loop, nested-loops

I've got a function that often throws an exception (SSH over 3g).

I'd like to keep trying to run `function()` every 10 seconds until it succeeds (doesn't throw an exception).

As I see it, there are two options:

**Nesting:**

```
def nestwrapper():
    try:
        output = function()
    except SSHException as e:
        # Try again
        sleep(10)
        return nestwrapper()
    return output
```

**Looping: (updated)**

It's been pointed out that the previous looping code was pretty unnecessary.

```
def loopwrapper():
    while True:
        try:
            return function()
        except SSHException as e:
            sleep(10)
```

---

Is there a preferred method of doing this?

Is there an issue with nesting and the exception stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find a loop to be cleaner and more efficient here.  If this is an automation job, the recursive method could hit python recursion limit (default is 1000 iirc, can check with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`).

Don't use `status is False` for your expression, because this is an identity comparison.  Use `while not status`.

I would probably implement it slightly differently too, because I don't see any need for the two different functions here:

```
def function_with_retries():
  while True:
    try:
      output = function()
    except SSHException:
      sleep(10)
    else:
      return output
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on `sys.getrecursionlimit()`!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it makes a heck of a lot of sense to specially wrap the function call twice.  the exception is probably reasonable, and you're going to the extra step of retrying on that particular exception.  What I mean is that the try/except is rather tightly involved with the retrying loop.

This is the way I normally do this:

```
def retry_something():
    while True:
        try:
            return something()
        except SomeSpecialError:
            sleep(10)
```

The `while True:` is really exactly what you're up to, you're going to loop forever, or rather, until you actually manage to `something()`, and then return.  There's no further need for a boolean flag of success, that's indicated by the normal case of the return statement (which politely escapes the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

```
function looper(f):
    while 1:
        try:
            return f()
        except SSHException, e:
            sleep(10)

output = looper(<function to call>)
```

Comment: The preferred way to get the handle to the exception instance is with the `as` keyword:  `except Exception as inst`.  I guess this is to avoid confusion of the syntax for checking multiple exception types in a tuple.

Comment: @wim I agree, `as` is more Pythonic, I cut and pasted from the original question.

Comment: @wim You're right, as of [PEP 3110](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/) (since 2.6). Cheers!